# MySQL select too large (join three tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I'm selecting a large dataset and it's taking an extremely large amount of time because of the one-to-many relationships of the joined tables.  I have three tables--simplified they are as follows:

### customers

```
| customers | CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `usertype` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `membershipid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `membershipid` (`membershipid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=980 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

### memberships

```
| memberships | CREATE TABLE `memberships` (
  `membershipid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `membership` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `flag` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`membershipid`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=316 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

### membership_contracts

```
| membership_contracts | CREATE TABLE `membership_contracts` (
   `bond_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `membership_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contract_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bond_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `membership_id` (`membership_id`,`contract_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1623 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

### contract_items

```
| contract_items | CREATE TABLE `contract_items` (
  `contract_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contract_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contract_item_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27398 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

There is a one to many relationship between the membership and contracts, and the contracts and contract items.

my current query is:

```
SELECT customers.username, contract_items.contract_id, so_on_and_so_forth
FROM   customers, memberships, membership_contracts, contract_items
WHERE  customers.membershipid=memberships.membershipid
AND    memberships.`membershipid=membership_contracts.membership_id
AND    membership_contracts.contract_id=contract_items.contract_id
AND    contract_items.item_id=user.item_id
```

so I have a small dataset (users and items) that's increased 600,000 lines (each membership has around 25 contracts and each contract can have over 1000 items) to only select items that are on a contract that the user has on their membership.

Is there a faster way to do this?  Am I using a join that I shouldn't be?  I have a unique index on membership_contracts for the ids, so at least that's minimal.
                    |

```
| id | select_type | table                | type   | possible_keys            | key           | key_len | ref                                                                                             | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | contract_items       | ALL    | NULL                     | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                                                                                            | 24691 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | order_details        | ref    | orderid,productid        | productid     | 4       | database123456789.contract_items.product_id                                                   |     2 |                                 |
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | orders               | eq_ref | PRIMARY,odsp,ospd,userid | PRIMARY       | 4       | database123456789.order_details.orderid                                                       |     1 |                                 |
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | customers            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,membershipid     | PRIMARY       | 4       | database123456789.orders.userid                                                               |     1 |                                 |
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | membership_contracts | ref    | membership_id            | membership_id | 9       | database123456789.customers.membershipid,database123456789.contract_items.contract_id       |    12 | Using where; Using index        |
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | memberships          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY       | 4       | database123456789.membership_contracts.membership_id                                          |     1 | Using where                     |
```

Comment: `EXPLAIN` plan and table (or at very least, index) definitions, please.

Comment: The tables are user/membership_contracts/contract_items and the fields are below delimited by a "|", what can I also explain?

Comment: I mean, use MySQL's [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain.html) command to obtain the execution plan: just stick the word `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and then [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23251744/edit) to include the results.  Please also include the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`, replacing `...` with each of the three used in your query.

Comment: I changed the post.  Can the differing charsets be the problem?

Comment: It could be, but until you post the `EXPLAIN` plan we won't know...

Comment: No, but those are the table definitions (also helpful).  Please stick the word `EXPLAIN` in front of your `SELECT` query and show the results of executing that.

Comment: The EXPLAIN is from a different query.

Comment: First thing to do is stop using implicit joins. They are an antipattern and should not be used in the 21st century ever.

Comment: query selects data from order_details and orders to get to `membershipid`.  I cut that portion out of my explanation to make it more simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"contract_items" table needs an index on contract_id field.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customers.username, contract_items.contract_id, so_on_and_so_forth
FROM   customers
join memberships on customers.membershipid=memberships.membershipid
join membership_contracts on  memberships.membershipid=membership_contracts.membership_id
join  contract_items on  membership_contracts.contract_id=contract_items.contract_id
WHERE      contract_items.item_id=user.item_id
```

When you put your query into joins you can immediately see that the where clause makes no sense as there is no user table in the joins. Your query should not run at all.

What is causing the problem with your real query (which you clearly haven't given us as your explain plan is clearly not for the query you gave us and what you gave us should not run at all)) is likely either one or more missing indexes (all FKs should be indexed) or an accidental cross join (which is one reason why implicit joins are an antipattern and it is a very bad practice to use them).